# JTree nodes won't get visually selected

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtree, treecellrenderer

Somehow I am not able to enable a "select highlight" for my JTree nodes.
I am working with a custom cell renderer in my project (which most likely causes this problem).

This is the full renderer class code:

```
protected class ProfessionTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    private final JLabel label;

    public ProfessionTreeCellRenderer() {
        label = new JLabel();

        setBackgroundSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Object o = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();

        if (o instanceof Profession) {
            Profession profession = (Profession) o;

            label.setIcon(profession.getIcon());
            label.setText(profession.getDisplayName());
        } else if(o instanceof NPC) {
            label.setIcon(QuestEdit.getIcon("npc"));
            label.setText(((NPC) o).getName());
        } else {
            label.setIcon(null);
            label.setText("" + value);
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

I searched on stackoverflow and other sites for possible solutions, found the "setOpaque" method - no change at all.

I am sure that it has to do something with the custom renderer, since the highlight is working perfectly fine in another project of mine.

**Edit:**

Removing the JLabel and adding those lines worked for me:

```
this.selected = selected;
this.hasFocus = hasFocus;           

if (selected) {
    super.setBackground(getBackgroundSelectionColor());
    setForeground(getTextSelectionColor());
} else {
    super.setBackground(getBackgroundNonSelectionColor());
    setForeground(getTextNonSelectionColor());
}
```

Comment: I faced this same issue and just add the code `this.selected = selected;
this.hasFocus = hasFocus;  ` it worked ,thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultTreeCellRenderer` extends JLabel, so try configuring `this` instead of `label`, then returning `this`.

Comment: @tbodt Thank you for the quick answer, will try that out later!

Answer (score 0):

After overriding the method as below :

```
getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus)
```

Create a JLabel instance with this code snippet:

```
JLabel label=(JLabel)super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
```

And then override the method `public Color getBackgroundSelectionColor()` to your own color.